# What will happen in this case of asynchronous execution?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

```
const deleteData = async (result) => {
  await Promise.all([
    deleteFromCollectionA(result),
    deleteFromCollectionB(result),
    deleteFromCollectionC(result),
  ]);
};

const recalculateData = async () => {
  const rows = await database("someTable");

  for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    const message = mapToMessage(record);
    await pushToQueue(message);
  }
};

const recalculate = async (result) => {
  await deleteData(result);
  await recalculateData(result);
};
```

The above code is in the service file. Here's the code in the controller

```
async function recalculate(req, res) {
  await recalculate();
}
```

Here's the route

```
router.post("/recalculate", recalculate);
```

I am having trouble understanding asynchronicity and what exactly will happen in this case.

deleteData() deletes documents from multiple MongoDb collections.

recalculateData() fetches records from a SQL db, iterates over them, does some mapping then it sends each one to a Kafka topic to be consumed by a service and processed. The results of that processing are inserted into the MongoDB collections.

Will recalculateDate wait until all documents that are supposed to be deleted are deleted for it to start executing ?

And what if recalculate() is executed at certain API endpoint, will it block handling requests at that particular endpoint until all the processing that recalculateData() initiated is done ? And by 'all processing' I mean that all records from SQL table is fetched and sent to the Kafka topic and the service that consumes from the Kafka topic is done processing all the messages that were pushed to that queue and the results are inserted into the multiple MongoDb collection.

Comment: It would clarify your question if you included some code that actually *calls* one of your functions. As it is, they're just functions.

Comment: @Pointy I thought I said recalculate() is executed at a request made to an endpoint. Anyway, I made some edits. Will you please take another look ?

Comment: You can't have two functions in the same module called "recalculate".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will recalculateDate wait until all documents that are supposed to be deleted are deleted for it to start executing ?

Yes, because you have awaited the promise returned by `Promise.all(...)` inside the `deleteData` function, and further awaited the promise returned by `deleteData(result)` inside the `recalculate` function, before calling `recalculateData(result)`.

> And what if recalculate() is executed at certain API endpoint, will it block handling requests at that particular endpoint until all the processing that recalculateData() initiated is done ?

No, it won't. Asynchronous operations will be handled in the background and in the meantime, the main thread can do other things, like handle other requests.

In other words, main thread can handle other requests while different `await` statements wait for the promises they are waiting for to settle.

> And by 'all processing' I mean that all records from SQL table is fetched and sent to the Kafka topic and the service that consumes from the Kafka topic is done processing all the messages that were pushed to that queue and the results are inserted into the multiple MongoDb collection.

If your consumers are executed on the same thread that handles the requests, they will block as long as the code is executed on the main thread. In other words, the synchronous code will block, for example, if processing includes performing some calculations or executing loops that are executed on the main thread.

Any asynchronous work they do, like saving records in MongoDB won't block the main thread.